# Check if Outlook MAPIFolder is visible?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

When I iterate through all Outlook folders (in a C# Add-In) I see folder names like:

- Yammer Root
- Sync Issues
- Subscriptions

**These folders are not visible in Outlook. I like to check in my code if the folder is visible or not but I don't find a property like Hidden or Visible.**

MAPIFolder folder has properties like:

- folder.DefaultItemType
- folder.Name

but not hidden.

**How can I find out in my c# Add-In if folders are hidden or not?**

Answer (score 1):

You will need to read the `PR_ATTR_HIDDEN` MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10F4000B`). You can read it using `MAPIFolder.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`.

You can see that (and other) property using [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IMAPIFolder button.

Answer (score 0):

At least on my machine I never retrieved a value for PR_ATTR_HIDDEN for all folders. I could not find out the reason although in OutlookSpy the value is true for the hidden folders.

Code:

```
        var rootFolder = outlook.Session.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder();
        foreach (Folder folder in rootFolder.Folders)
        {
            try
            {
                bool isHidden = folder.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10F4000B");
                // never reach this line
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                // always exception: value is not available
            }
        }
```

My workaround: If you want to retrieve the folders as they are displayed in Outlook you can use PR_CONTAINER_CLASS_W and compare it with IPF.Note or IPF.Imap.

Sample:

```
        const string PR_CONTAINER_CLASS_W = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3613001F";

        string containerClass = folder.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_CONTAINER_CLASS_W);
        bool isVisible = string.Equals(containerClass, "IPF.Note")|| string.Equals(containerClass, "IPF.Imap");
```

Comment: Your late answer is not better then the already accepted answer

Comment: Stephan, I don't say the answer is better. I just wanted to give the developers who experience similiar problems with PR_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN an additional way to determine if a folder is visible or not.